# use authentication with twitter account in Sencha Touch mobile application

Tags: twitter, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I would like to know how to implement authentication  with `twitter` account in `sencha` mobile application ?

Comment: did you see [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter) doc

Answer (score 1):

If you incorporate Windows Azure, you can use the new Sencha Touch Extensions for Windows Azure -- which include authentication via Twitter, Facebook, Google and Microsoft:

- https://market.sencha.com/extensions/sencha-touch-extensions-for-windows-azure